# Filtering datagridview from another form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

So I am making project in Windows Forms and need a little help.

In my first Form I am importing data from a local sql database into DataGridView, which is about Client Money Transfers.

Now I need to make a Filter for my DataGridView, for example display all Client data which has transfers with more than 1500$.

Such queries can have more than one parameter.

So am I Calling another Form on buttonClick to enter all Filter parameters.

After entering parameters on ButtonClick I need to filter data in DGV which is in first Form. But I don't know how to change DGV from another Form. I was trying to call form1 by this way:

`Form form1 = new Form();`

But I can not still reach DataGridView.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't reference the original form, it creates a *new* one:

```
Form form1 = new Form();
```

So anything you do on that variable happens to a second in-memory, non-visible form.

Presumably, somewhere on your main form, you are doing something like this in order to show your second form with the filter logic, correct?:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

What you can do is pass a reference to the current form through that constructor, so that `Form2` would have a reference back to the main form.  So in the `Form2` constructor, you might do something like this:

```
private Form1 parentForm;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.parentForm = form1;
}
```

So anywhere else in your `Form2` code, you can reference that parent form:

```
this.parentForm.SomeMethodCall();
```

Then in `Form1` when you show the `Form2` instance, it can pass a reference to itself:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

At that point `Form2` can now reference any *public* functionality exposed by `Form1`.  Public properties, public methods, etc.  So whatever logic needs to happen on `Form1`, just expose a method to do it and call that method from `Form2`.

Answer (score 0):

From your initial form where you have the button click event you can call your second filtering form like this :

```
using ( Form  form2 =  new Form())
{
    if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
         //apply data filtering based on what you got from form2
    }
}
```