# How to make a filter in DataGridView with two forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkedlistbox

I have 2 Windows Forms. On the first form, I have a DataGridView and on the second form, I have just a few checkedListBoxes.

I found this question similar to my: [Filtering datagridview from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902151/filtering-datagridview-from-another-form)

It's looking similar to my problem, but it's not saying how I can filter information from the second form.

Also, I already asked something about this project: [How can I load in Windows Forms? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706395/how-can-i-load-in-windows-forms-c)

It can help to understand better this situation.

[image]

My idea is that you have to put some marks on the second form and it's saving right now what you click, but I need to get those clicks on the first form for DGV.

**The question is: How to make a filter with two forms?**

Code:

```
 private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.InitializeSecondForm();
        form2.Show();
    } 

 public void InitializeSecondForm()
    {
        this.Height = Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormHeight;
        this.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormWidth;
        this.Location = Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormLocation;
        this.collectionOfTags = Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings;

        this.FormClosing += SecondFormClosingEventHandler;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    } 
 private void SecondFormClosingEventHandler(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormHeight = this.Height;
        Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormWidth = this.Width;
        Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormLocation = this.Location;
        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings = this.collectionOfTags;

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    } 
 private void fileListDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        DicomFileInfo dicomFile = new DicomFileInfo();

        DataGridView datas = new DataGridView();
        
        datas.DataSource = dicomFile;

        for(int i = 0; i < datas.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();

            datas[2, i] = linkCell;
        }
    }
```

This code for Second Form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    StringCollection collectionOfTags = new StringCollection();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeSecondForm();

        LoadSettings();
    }

    
    private void LoadSettings()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var d = checkedListBox1.Items[i];
            if (collectionOfTags.Contains(d.ToString()))
            {
                int index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(d);
                if (index != -1)
                    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var d = checkedListBox2.Items[i];
            if (collectionOfTags.Contains(d.ToString()))
            {
                int index = checkedListBox2.Items.IndexOf(d);
                if (index != -1)
                    checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox3.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var d = checkedListBox3.Items[i];
            if (collectionOfTags.Contains(d.ToString()))
            {
                int index = checkedListBox3.Items.IndexOf(d);
                if (index != -1)
                    checkedListBox3.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox4.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var d = checkedListBox4.Items[i];
            if (collectionOfTags.Contains(d.ToString()))
            {
                int index = checkedListBox4.Items.IndexOf(d);
                if (index != -1)
                    checkedListBox4.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox5.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var d = checkedListBox5.Items[i];
            if (collectionOfTags.Contains(d.ToString()))
            {
                int index = checkedListBox5.Items.IndexOf(d);
                if (index != -1)
                    checkedListBox5.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox6.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var d = checkedListBox6.Items[i];
            if (collectionOfTags.Contains(d.ToString()))
            {
                int index = checkedListBox6.Items.IndexOf(d);
                if (index != -1)
                    checkedListBox6.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
        }

    }

    public void InitializeSecondForm()
    {
        this.Height = Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormHeight;
        this.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormWidth;
        this.Location = Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormLocation;
        this.collectionOfTags = Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings;

        this.FormClosing += SecondFormClosingEventHandler;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    }

    private void SecondFormClosingEventHandler(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormHeight = this.Height;
        Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormWidth = this.Width;
        Properties.Settings.Default.SecondFormLocation = this.Location;
        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings = this.collectionOfTags;

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings.Clear();

        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings
.AddRange(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        foreach (string s in Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(s);
            if (index != -1) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
            }

        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings
.AddRange(checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        foreach (string t in Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox2.Items.IndexOf(t);
            if (index != -1) checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings
.AddRange(checkedListBox3.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        foreach (string c in Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox3.Items.IndexOf(c);
            if (index != -1) checkedListBox3.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings
.AddRange(checkedListBox4.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        foreach (string a in Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox4.Items.IndexOf(a);
            if (index != -1) checkedListBox4.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings
.AddRange(checkedListBox5.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        foreach (string k in Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox5.Items.IndexOf(k);
            if (index != -1) checkedListBox5.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings
 .AddRange(checkedListBox6.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
        foreach (string q in Properties.Settings.Default.DICOMTagSettings)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox6.Items.IndexOf(q);
            if (index != -1) checkedListBox6.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: So you have 2 form-windows with 2 different datasources and another where you can hit some checkboxes to filter the data showed on the 2 forms?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger I have 2 forms only. On the first form, I can click on the button for file, and then will show the second form. On the second form, you can filter, which items you need to see on your first form in DataGridView.

Comment: I see the pictures help a lot

Comment: Do you want the results grid to change dynamically on the first form as you tick in the second form, or will you click OK and then the filtering is performed? What flow of program are you expecting? How will different categories of filter combine? "OR within, AND between?"

Comment: The linkes answer __will__ show you the way. You need to have references between the forms.

Comment: I can't quite work out if the Form2 is "picking which columns to show" or "picking which rows to show" ...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a way to send data from one object to another. There are many possibilities but the most cleanest ones are either implementing the Observer Pattern or make use of events which is the simplest form to implement the Observer Pattern.

Much like you subscribe to a Buttons clickevent from the form, you can also expose events yourself and with the corresponding eventargs send data to whatever is subscribed to your events:

```
public class Form1 // ignore class names it's just to demonstrate =)
{
    // ... other code

    public void PickTags_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // i suppose you instanciate the form here...
    
        var filterForm = new FormWithFilters();
    
        filterForm.FilterChanged += OnFilterChanged; // here you subscribe
        filterForm.Show();
     }

    public void OnFilterChanged(object sender, FilterEventArgs args)
    {
        // ... apply your filter
    }
}

public class FormWithFilters
{
    // ... other code
    
    public void YourUiHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // collect the data for the filter
        
        var eventArgs = new FilterEventArgs
        {
            // assign your Properties for the subscribers to consume
        };
        
        FilterChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs); // notify subscribers
    }
    
    
    public event EventHandler<FilterEventArgs> FilterChanged; // your very own event
}

public class FilterEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // add whatever properties you need to communicate what has to be filtered...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear “when” you want to update the grid in form 1. With over 40 options for the user to choose from, then I would think that you would update the grid when the user clicks the OK button on form 2. In that situation, you could use a `ShowDialog` for form 2 and after form 2 is closed, your code should still be able to grab any “public” variables in form 2. So if you make the `CheckListBox`(s) in form 2 “public” then you can examine them in form 1 like below.

```
private void buttonToOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.ShowDialog();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.AppendLine("Checked Options are: ... ");
  for (int i = 0; i < f2.checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
    sb.AppendLine("Option: " + f2.checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("          " + (f2.checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) ? " Is" : "Is Not") + " Checked");
  }
  textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

[image]

Obviously if form 2 does NOT expose the `CheckedListBoxes` as public, then you will not be able to see them in form 1. In the designer for form 2… select the `CheckListBox`(s) and change the `Modifier` property to `true`.

***Edit...***

Try the pseudo code below which is incomplete. I made a “global” `List<string>` `collectionOfTagsMaster` that keeps a list of all the tags. When the second from is closed, the code creates a new list of all tags, then loops though the `CheckedListBox` box on form2. If the tag is NOT checked then we remove that tag from `curTags` list of tags. If the tag IS checked then we leave the tag in the list.

After that a simple loop through all the columns in the grid to set it visible or invisible depending on if its column name is contained in the `curTags` collection. In my small tests, using a grid with a data table data source worked as expected.

```
List<string> collectionOfTagsMaster = new List<string>();
// fill list with all tags

private void buttonToOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.ShowDialog();
  List<string> curTags = new List<string>(collectionOfTagsMaster);
  for (int i = 0; i < f2.checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
    if (!f2.checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)) {
      curTags.Remove(f2.checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    }
  }
  foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns) {
    if (curTags.Contains(column.Name)) {
      column.Visible = true;
    }
    else {
      column.Visible = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, can you explain the code in the `fileListDataGridView_CellContentClick` event. It looks odd and appears to accomplish nothing. Can you explain what the code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: But in my case, you have to check which one was clicked on in the second form, and then you have to show only those in the first form. Your answer is useful, but not in my case.

Comment: What do you mean by… _”… you have to check which one was clicked on in the second form …”_ … ? …

Comment: We have checklistboxes where we can click on some of them and that means that we choose some parameters. Those parameters like you showed on the second form. And when you press ok on the second form it should show on the first form only those parameters which we choose. I added a picture of those forms, it should help.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but when we will know which boxes were checked then we need to show only those tags on the first form. Your solution is close to the final, but not helping me to show on the first form tags.

Comment: Hmmm … Maybe I am missing something… The second to last sentence in your question… _”My idea is that you have to put some marks on the second form and it's saving right now what you click, but I need to get those clicks on the first form for DGV.”_ … my answer should help in that regard. Then the last sentence… _”The question is: How to make a filter with two forms?”_ … ? … I may be missing what you mean by “filter” and “two forms”…  I assumed to “filter” out form1’s grid columns from the unchecked boxes on from2.

Comment: Yeah, it's not so easy to say and I'm also a student and everything is new to me. I would like to just get on the first form only those tags, which we picked in the second form. Right now I can save what I picked in this form, but I need also to check which one was picked and then show it on the first form. Is it ok? Or do I need to explain it somehow more? I will do it, just need to understand how :)

Comment: _“but I need also to check which one was picked and then show it on the first form.”_ … what does this mean… ? … my answer shows how to _check which one was picked_ … it is not clear by what you mean by _show it on the first form_ … ? … Show it where? You need to clarify what you are asking and quit moving the goal post.

Comment: How I understood right now, it should be something with Settings.settings, that means I will save my checked checkboxes from the Second Form there and somehow I can use it in First Form, anyway, I didn't find an answer yet.

Comment: _”How I understood right now, it should be something with Settings.settings,…”_ … why do think it should be “something” done with “Settings.setting”? And instead of going back and forth… can you tell me “how” my answer does NOT answer your question in reference to getting the check box values from form2 IN form1… my code does just that and demonstrates this. What part of my answer does NOT solve your question?

Comment: I'm using DataGridView and you are using just a text box that's the difference. Can you say how to do this with DataGridView?

Comment: You have shown no code. Please show your latest attempt. It is a guess as to “what” particular part of this you may be having issues with… adding/hiding the grid columns? You know which columns to display in the grid, so instead of _”using just a text box.”_ … the code `grid.Column[“X”].Visible = true` … or … `grid.Column[“X”].Visible = false` … would also work.

Comment: I added almost everything, I think right now it's more clear :)